# How to delete all records which is 24 hours old using django ORM?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

Model:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    option1 = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=False)
    option1_vote = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    option2 = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=False)
    option2_vote = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    option3 = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=False)
    option3_vote = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    option4 = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=False)
    option4_vote = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    date_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

We have the date_time field here.

```
Question.objects.filter(condition).delete()
```

what condition should I put there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Python [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta).

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
last_24h = datetime.now() - timedelta(hours=24)

Question.objects.filter(date_time__lte=last24h).delete()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`timedelta()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta) and [`Now()`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/b92ffebb0cdc469baaf1b8f0e72dddb069eb2fb4/django/db/models/functions/datetime.py#L214) from functions library.

Try this:

```py
from datetime import timedelta
from django.db.models.functions import Now

Question.objects.filter(date_time__lte=Now()-timedelta(days=1)).delete()
```